# How do I stop the program and restart with sudo without the user typing the word sudo?

Tags: rust, sudo

```rust
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let mut source_list = OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .append(true)
        .open("/usr/local/etc/apt/sources.list")
        .unwrap();

    if let Err(e) = writeln!(source_list, "{}", "deb ".to_owned() + "https://www.google.com/" + " ./") {
        eprintln!("Couldn't write to file: {}", e);
    }
}
```

When running this code without sudo it outputs:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 13, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Permission denied" }', src/libcore/result.rs:999:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

and when running this code with sudo it asks for my password and then writes to the file successfully so my question is how do I get it to ask for me my password then write to the file successfully without the need of sudo (Basically how do I make it run sudo for the user so they don't have to)?

Comment: *"Basically how do I make it run sudo for the user so they don't have to"*. You can't. But you can detect you don't have the permissions and politely ask the user to launch the program with the relevant rights.

Comment: @DenysSéguret you actually just gave me an idea on how to do it, how do I detect if the user doesn't have the permissions?

Comment: You just wrote the error to detect: `code: 13, kind: PermissionDenied`. The right way is to try, then to analyze the error. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html#method.kind

Comment: @DenysSéguret do you have a code example on how to detect it? Or could I actually run code if I get an error with unwrap_or_else?

Comment: This was a little too hard to write in comment so I made an answer

Comment: An alternative approach: open a pipe to `sudo sh -c "cat >>/usr/local/etc/apt/sources.list"` instead of opening the file directly. This dramatically cuts down on the amount of weird stuff that can happen. It's still inadvisable to edit `sources.list` (or any system config file) programmatically unless you *really* know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you *could*, but if you *should* is another question...

When detecting the lack of privileges you could restart your program with sudo with [`std::process::Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.spawn) and unix is extensions [`exec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/os/unix/process/trait.CommandExt.html#tymethod.exec) by executing a command with the same cmdline arguments. [`env::args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/env/struct.Args.html) is an iterator to all command line arguments where the first one is the program name

```
use std::process::Command;
use std::os::unix::process::CommandExt;

 [...]
 // when restart as root is needed
 let cmdlineargs:Vec<String>=env::args().collect();
 let _output = Command::new("sudo")
                    .args(&cmdlineargs)
                    .exec(); // Bye bye never returns
```

There are a ton of problems with the code above, for instance you should avoid having the program to restart itself in an indefinite loop and hiding privilege escalations from users is often considered bad design.

*Edit: Updated after suggestions in comments replaced `spawn` with `exec`*

Comment: This is a very bad practice. Please stick to the normal unix way of dealing with rights, don't try to do a stealth sudo. And this would only work if the user recently did a sudo and gave his password.

Comment: I agree this is bad unix-practice as I write above, the point is it is however it is possible if someone wants to write this kind of hacks.

Comment: Note that if you really want to escalate privileges like that, you should probably use [`exec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/os/unix/process/trait.CommandExt.html#tymethod.exec) in order to avoid issues with sharing the TTY between the original and spawned process.

Comment: `cmdlineargs[0]` is not guaranteed to contain a string that can be passed to `sudo` to run the same program again. It is likely to work in simple cases, but I can think of several ways to stymie it.

Answer (score 4):

> Basically how do I make it run sudo for the user so they don't have to

You can't.

The normal way of dealing with this problem is to try, and, when it fails, analyze the error and politely ask the user to launch the program with the relevant rights:

```rust
let source_list = openoptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .append(true)
        .open("/usr/local/etc/apt/sources.list");
match source_list {
    Err(ioerr) => {
        match ioerr.kind() {
            ErrorKind::PermissionDenied => {
                e.println("permission denied. Maybe sudo?");
            }
            _ => {
                e.println("I failed :(");
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    Ok(source_list) => {
        // do things
    }
}
```